# How to use a Static Binding in SXA Scriban

Tags: sxa, scriban

Is there a way to use a static Binding (View Rendering) in SXA Scriban Variant ?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can embed a rendering within a scriban template with a combination of `sc_execute` and using a `Component` child item:

[image: Component Child Item]

The `Component` child item allows you to embed a component, you would select the rendering item and populate the required rendering parameters. You can also select a datasource item if that is required.

In your scriban template, you can then use the `sc_execute` function to "execute" the child `Component` item.

Call it like this:

```
sc_execute i_item "The Component Item Name"
```

The `i_item` can be any Sitecore item that gets passed through to the component as a datasource. Please see the documentation below for more details on the scriban functions.

References:

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/create-a-rendering-variant.html
- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html#sc_execute